# How can i get this warn out from my project?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get rid of the following warning out in my project? My team doesn't have this warning like me.

> npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN angular2-daterangepicker@0.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN angular2-daterangepicker@0.0.5 requires a peer of bootstrap@^3.3.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN angular2-daterangepicker@0.0.5 requires a peer of jquery@^2.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN angular2-daterangepicker@0.0.5 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN angular2-daterangepicker@0.0.5 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN ng2-daterangepicker@2.0.12 requires a peer of @types/jquery@^3.2.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN thruway.js@1.2.13 requires a peer of ws@^2.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN tsickle@0.24.1 requires a peer of typescript@2.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Install the packages that the warnings tell you to install?

Comment: Screenshots are nice but the error message should also be added as text to make it searchable.

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install peer-package` on every required peer package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try updating all angular packages as follows:

```
npm install typescript@latest --save-dev

npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest --save
```

Comment: This is wrong. You must have exact version of typescript for angular.

Comment: Just FYI, `npm install typescript@latest` This works.